# string not being read first time around

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char* string;

int main(void)
{
    char *names[6];
    int num_entries = 0,i=0,size=0;
    string name = (string) malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);

    printf("\nHow many names do you want to enter ? \n");
    scanf("%d",&num_entries);

    for(i=0 ; i < num_entries ; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a name : ");
        gets(name);
        size = strlen(name);
        names[i] = (string) malloc(sizeof(char)*size + 1);
        strcpy(names[i],name);
    }

    for(i=0 ; i < num_entries ; i++)
        puts(names[i]);

}
```

in this program the string is not read the first time around the loop,however works fine for all subsequent calls,the program simply has to accept n strings,store and display them. owever it executes n-1 times.Solution?also,feel free to point any mistakes in the way pointers,allocation etc. is used,any feedback appreciated .

Comment: `gets()` is evil. Consider using `fgets()` instead. See the BUGS section near the bottom of this page: http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=fgets&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en

Comment: changed the gets() call to fgets(name,16,stdin) still same bug

Comment: @alk was just making a comment for improvement, not offering an answer to the problem. That's why it's a comment, not an answer. :) Here's another comment: the preinitializers for your integers are superfluous since you always set them anyway. :)

Comment: @mbratch: 1st: Thanks for explaining my intention. 2nd: Although the preinit/s indeed aren't necessary, I'd prefer to not have uninitialised variables hanging around. This leads to my next comment for improvement: Declare variables where you need them, and this **isn't the top** of the method in most cases.

Comment: No worries, alk. Sounds logical.

Comment: One more: In C do not cast the result of `malloc/calloc/realloc` as it is not necessary nor recommended. For detail please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576

Comment: Another one: Always check the result of (more or less any) system call. In your case `malloc()` may return `NULL`. Dereferencing `NULL` will lead to undefined behaviuor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `gets` before the loop to discard the new line left by `scanf`.

Or better yet, use the standard *workaround* to discard unread input:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Comment: `char c;
  while((c=getchar()!='\n')&& c!= EOF)
  {    name[i] = c;
      i++;    }
  name[i] = '\0'; ` something like this?

Comment: @superuser47, `getchar` returns an `int` and so `int c` is what's generally used as Anthony shows. And his suggestion was just to use it to gobble up characters until the next line feed. If you want to change your code to use it as the mechanism for reading the `name`, then it would be good to show that as an edit to your original post if you have further questions on it.

Comment: superuser, you have mistaken the intent of the code. Just use it - as is -  after `scanf("%d",&num_entries);` and before the loop, to discard the newline.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here, which is typical of the `scanf` statement, is that it does not use the newline when you entered the number of names you wanted and pressed "enter".

As a result, the newline is stuck in the stdin buffer until you do your next read, which in this case is the first name you try to read, so your first name is simply "newline". To deal with this, use `getchar()` to eat up the newline character so you don't have that issue anymore.

Typically, as a rule of thumb, you'll almost always want to use a `getchar()` or something similar after a `scanf` statement to deal with this issue.

I've modified your code below and works fine for me. I also cleaned it up a bit since some lines were not necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char* string;

int main(void)
{
    string names[6];
    int num_entries=0, i=0;
    string name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);

    printf("\nHow many names do you want to enter ? \n");
    scanf("%d",&num_entries);
    getchar();
    for(i=0 ; i < num_entries ; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a name : ");
        fgets(name,16,stdin);
        names[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(name) + 1);
        strcpy(names[i],name);
    }

    for(i=0 ; i < num_entries ; i++)
        puts(names[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you've already declared a typedef for string, you can just use `string names[6]` instead of `char *names[6]`. As for `fgets`, it'll prevent you from doing overflows on your limited string size of 16 chars.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code with all suggestions. Note that Anthony Accioly gets credit for the answer.

```
int main(void)
{
    char *names[6];
    int num_entries = 0, i = 0, size = 0, c = 0;
    string name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);

    if ( !name )
    {
        printf( "Unable to allocate memory for name\n" );
        return(1);
    }

    printf("\nHow many names do you want to enter ? \n");
    scanf("%d",&num_entries);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    for( i = 0 ; i < num_entries; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a name : ");
        gets(name);
        size = strlen(name);
        names[i] = (string) malloc(sizeof(char)*size + 1);
        strcpy(names[i],name);
    }

    for(i=0 ; i < num_entries ; i++)
        puts(names[i]);

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fflush(stdin);` as an alternative to `getchar()` or the `while(...)` statement.

P.S.: I am sorry for writing my suggestion here, as I do not have enough reputation to comment.